# Can WebGL fail to keep up with requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: webgl, requestanimationframe

Lets say I have a WebGL loop like this:

```
function draw(timestamp)
{
    // ...
    gl.drawArrays(...);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

I'm afraid of the possibility of the following problem:

- My requestAnimationFrame callback "draw" gets called by the browser about 60 times per second.
- gl.drawArrays returns immediately, but the underlying job takes the GPU longer than 1/60 of a second to execute.
- I end up making gl.drawArrays() calls faster than the GPU can execute them.

Questions:

1. Can this problem actually occur in theory? If so, what is the right way to deal with it? If not, then why?
2. Is the "requestAnimationFrame callback" guaranteed to not be called until all my previous WebGL calls have completed for all the canvas elements on the page? If so, then is it documented in the specs? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the problem can't happen.

Should probably close this as a duplicate but to know why you should read up on [the browser's event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Basically the browser runs like this

```
   const tasks = [];

   // loop forever
   for (;;)  {  
     // execute all tasks
     while (tasks.length) {
       const task = tasks.shift();
       task();
     }
     goToSleepUntilThereAreNewTasks();
   }
```

It never runs JavaScript in parallel (except for workers) so your `requestAnimationFrame` callback will not get called in the middle of another `requestAnimationFrame` callback.

All `requestAnimationFrame` does is says is effectively "next time browser is going to repaint the screen add this callback to the list of tasks to run".

All other things in the browser happen the same. When you load a page a task is added to execute your scripts. When you add a `setTimeout` the browser will add your callback to the list of tasks in however many milliseconds you set the timer for. When you add event listeners for things like `mousemove` or `keydown` or `img.onload` the browser just adds tasks to the task list when the mouse moves or a key is pressed or an image finishes loading.

The important part is there is no parallel work from the POV of JavaScript. Each task runs to completion and the browser never processes any other task until the current task finishes running.

As for documentation that's in [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html#animation-frames)

---

Note that the browser can not composite the page without somehow waiting for your WebGL draw calls to fill out the canvas's drawingbuffer. It can run things in parallel, not JavaScript itself but for example executing previously submitted GPU commands while JavaScript is adding new ones or doing something else, but eventually it will block.

Consider that from the POV of JavaScript it's running requestAnimationFrames serially. One happens, it requests the next one. From the POV of the compositor, which is the code that draws all the DOM elements into the browser window, it's running in parallel to JavaScript taking the last state of the DOM and drawing the next frame in the browser. Part of that is waiting for the calls in WebGL. It doesn't need to do a hard wait like a `gl.finish`. It just needs to organize the GPU commands in such a way so that the compositing GPU commands happen after the last WebGL commands. The compositor itself is not going to start rendering new frames until it finished the current frame and it is the compositor that is effectively deciding it's time for a new frame, deciding it's time for a new frame is the trigger for executing a requestAnimationFrame event.

At best the browser will double or triple buffer such that while the browser is compositing this frame it can let JavaScript start queuing up commands for the next frame so there is more parallelism but again, it's not going to issue infinite requestAnimationFrame callbacks without waiting for the frame(s) it's generating to finish one way or another.

So no, the problem you pointed out can't happen.

---

note: the section above between the 2 separators didn't exist originally. Kaiido pointed out in comment they didn't think I answered the question. I thought I did implicitly. The implications of the event loop, are that

1. rAF events don't execute until the browser has decided it's time to draw the page
2. It's not going to decide to draw the page again if it's currently in the middle of drawing the page for the current frame
3. It obviously can't finish drawing the page until the commands you issued to the canvas via WebGL are finished executing.

Step 3 seems kind of obvious and not need to be stated. How could the browser draw the page if it it didn't wait for the canvas to have the image you drew into it? From that the rest falls out from the event loop implications. Why would the browser start a new frame if it's not finished with the current one? It wouldn't. If it hasn't started a new frame then it's not going to call your rAF callback.

I also want to be clear it's a reasonable question to ask. Like I mentioned above the browser might let JavaScript start making the next frame while it's busy compositing the current frame. If the browser does let JavaScript start the next frame in parallel and did nothing to throttle your problem could happen. One way or another the browser will synchronize with the GPU and make sure that the frames it has submitted to the GPU have finished executing before it gets too many frames ahead (1 or 2 frames). In OpenGL terms it can easily do this with [sync objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sync_Object). I'm not saying the browser uses sync objects. Only that the browser can do something similar to make sure it doesn't get too many frames ahead.

---

I don't know if this will make things more or less confusing but Kaiido points out in a chat discussion that if you use `setTimeout` instead of `requestAnimationFrame` then in a sense you'd get the issue you are worried about.

Let's say you do did this

```
function draw(timestamp)
{
    // ...
    gl.drawArrays(...);

    setTimeout(draw);
}
```

In this case with setTimeout of 0 (or any number under one frame) how many GPU commands get issued between composites is unknown. Maybe it calls `draw` 5 times between composites or 500 times. It is undefined and up to the browser.

The thing that I'd point out is that calling `draw` via `setTimeout` many times between composites is not "frames" it's just a really obfusticated way of issuing more GPU work. There is no functional difference between `draw` getting called N times between composites via N setTimeouts or by just a simple `for (let i = 0; i < N; ++i) { draw(); }` loop. In both cases a bunch of work got added to the GPU between composites. The only difference with the `setTimeout` method is the browser choses `N` for you.

This is actually one of the major points of using `requestAnimationFrame` because `setTimeout` has no relation to frames whatsoever.

Comment: That's not answering the question here. They are saying that `gl.drawArrays()` returns immediately, so the js can continue right after, and once the task is done, the event loop can continue its routine with other tasks. But they are worried about the GPU call, which according to OP is done in parallel. What if this call takes say a few seconds, then the event loop will have done a few thousands new calls, which will just add up to the GPU calls. So the question I guess really is *does the "update the rendering" steps in the event loop internally wait for gl.finish()*

Comment: The second question is "Is the "requestAnimationFrame callback" guaranteed to not be called until all my previous WebGL calls have completed for all the canvas elements on the page?" The answer is effectively "yes". Because in order to composite the page the browser has to wait for for WebGL's draw calls. So it's not going to issue another rAF because because of the event loop. The browser might triple buffer, but at one point or another it can't draw the page until your draw calls are done

Comment: "Because in order to composite the page the browser has to wait for for WebGL's draw calls" then that is the answer to the question, but it's not in your answer, nor in any of your links.

Comment: It's implied in my answer IMO but sure I can add those details

Comment: Thanks for the edits, not sure all these "note:" are needed though, and I still feel the first paragraph doesn't hit the question, it still presents the browser's event loop as something simple à-la node.js, and it still fails to mention "rendering opportunities", which should be the key here. Now, the addendum now implies that the browser will indeed wait for the GPU to finish before setting the "can-render" flag to true. I assume it's true to some extents, but does that mean that OP could actually face the problem they mentioned if they were using an other scheduling method?

Comment: note: I tried to force this state, but failed, always blocking the js task instead, but my web-gl skills are very very low... I'm also curious about how things would get syncced now with OffscreenCanvas.

Comment: What does offscreencanvas add to this? If you're asking if you can saturate the GPU then yes. Just submit commands forever and never return from your event. Same with saturating the CPU. Just declare an infinite loop. Can you make the browser run slower than 60fps? Yes. Just give it more work to do than can be run at 60fps. Can you get many "frames" ahead of the compositor? no, because the browser isn't going to ask for another frame until the previous frame (+1 or 2) have finished.

Comment: Offscreencanvas adds to this that now you can have two browsing contexts sharing the same GPU context but not the same event loop. To "Submit commands forever and never return from your event" would simply block the event loop, not useful here. *"the browser isn't going to ask for another frame"* only applies for the "update the rendering" step of the event loop, so once again, does this mean OP's case could happen if they were using an other scheduling method, like setTimeout?

Comment: They didn't ask about setTimeout but there is no getting ahead of frames with setTimeout since setTimeout has nothing to do with frames. There is just giving the GPU too much work to do. You can always give the GPU (or CPU) to much work to do. My examples of infinite loop examples were again implicit. Make a loop that takes 30 seconds to complete. Nothing changes. Sure you can give the browser too much work. That seems completely and utterly obvious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217865/discussion-between-kaiido-and-gman).

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Thanks Kaiido for your clarifications as well. I see what you mean. Those specs explain a lot, but still, I can't find where it says that the "compositor" will wait for my draw calls instead of taking the buffer in whatever state it happens to be at the time. I guess no sane browser would do this, because then it wouldn't know which of my WebGL calls is the final one, and which is supposed to be the first one in the next frame.